# HTML Div Alignment

Tags: css, html, alignment, vertical-alignment

I can't seem to figure out how to align a few of these divs (mostly just centering). I want the page to essentially look as close to this image as possible:

http://s7.postimg.org/saf158dqj/Test_Img.jpg

Namely 
1) I want the text in the header to be centered vertically (and I'd like to put it inside a separate div with bg color black);
2) I'd like the separate square, colored divs within the body to be equally spaced and centered on the screen (preferably relative to screen size);
3) I want the footer (hr and text) to span the entire bottom just short of the margins of the black div (with copyright floated left and contact floated right), though the current code squishes it to the left.

Here is the code that I currently have (sorry for the length): And thanks ahead of time for any help!

```
<html>
```

```
    /* Styles for All Pages */

    html {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        /* Sizing Properties */
        height: 100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background-color: white;
        color: white;
    }

    header, footer, nav { 
        display: block; 
    }

    #innerBodyDiv {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0% 10% 0% 10%; /*Leaves space on left and right to show background */
        background-color: black;
    }

    /* Styles for Header & Footer */

        /* Header */

        #header {

            height: 10%;
            width: auto;
            background-color: teal;
        }

        #header a ,a:hover, a:visited{
            color:white;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #divInHeader {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Microsoft PhagsPa;
        }

        /* Home Page Nav Divs Properties */

        #divOuterHomePageNav {

        }

        divInnerHomePageNav {

        }

        .squaresBox {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            text-align: center;
        }   

        .squaresText {
            text-align: center;
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .leftFloat {
            float: left;
        }

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }

        /* Header & Footer Styles */

        #footer {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0;
            color: white;
            padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
        }

        #copyright {
            float:left;
        }

        #contact {
            float:right;
        }

        #footer a{
            color: teal;
            text-decoration:none;
        }

        #footer a:hover, a:visited:hover{
            color: white;
        }


        #footerText {
            padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
        }


        /* HomePage Nav and Multi-Page Nav Colors */

        .colorWebDesign {
            background-color: #0b8140;
        }

        .colorGraphicDesign {
            background-color: #35459c;
        }

        .colorPhotography {
            background-color: #4d2a7c;
        }

        .colorVideo {
            background-color: #e9292a;
        }

        .colorAudio {
            background-color: #faa41a;
        }

        .colorWriting {
            background-color: #FFD801;
        }



 </STYLE>
```

```
<div id="innerBodyDiv">

    <!-- Header -->
    <header id="header">
    <a href="index.html">
        <div id="divInHeader">
            <h1>My Name</h1>
        </div>
    </a>
    </header>

    <!-- Home Page Nav -->
    <div id="divOuterHomePageNav">
        <div id="divInnerHomePageNav">
            <a href="webdesign.html">
                <div class="squaresBox leftFloat colorWebDesign">
                    <span class="squaresText">Web <br> Design</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="graphicdesign.html" >
                <div class="squaresBox leftFloat colorGraphicDesign">
                    <span class="squaresText">Graphic <br> Design</span>
                </div>
            </a>

                <div class="squaresBox leftFloat colorPhotography">
                    <span class="squaresText">Photography</span>
                </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

            <a href="video.html" >
                <div class="squaresBox leftFloat colorVideo">
                    <span class="squaresText">Video</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="audio.html" >
                <div class="squaresBox leftFloat colorAudio">
                    <span class="squaresText">Audio</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="writing.html" >
                <div class="squaresBox leftFloat colorWriting">
                    <span class="squaresText">Creative <br> Writing</span>
                </div>
            </a>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <footer id="footer">

        <hr>
        <div id="footerText">
            <span id="copyright">&copy; Copyright</span>
            <a href="contact.html" id="contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For each `<div>` in the CSS, use:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Comment: This should center your elements appropriately

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something like this before, have you tried

```
text-align: center;
```

in the CSS page?